# Issue with login ReturnURL in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am bulking up the security of a web application. (session/membership cookie expiration to be exact). I have noticed something odd when I attempt to navigate to a page before authenticated. The page works when logged in, put when I attempt to go to it before logging in, I get redirected to the login page(normal), but then the location I am sent to is not correct. It seems that it is missing the area in the URL. I was wondering if maybe this has to do with the routes?

Here is some more information:

Code from web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/logininformation/loginhomepage" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

- Original URL: `mysite.com/Display/Page/Index/62`
- URL After redirect to login: `mysite.com/logininformation/loginhomepage?ReturnUrl=%2fPage%2fIndex%2f62`
- URL after logged in: `mysite.com/Page/Index/62`

code from login controller:

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have custom route for the "area", try something like below under your login route in your RouteConfig.cs file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomRoute",
    url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```